# Does resistance depend on shape of conductor?

Tags: resistors

The area,length and material is same. Example a circular and square crosssection having same area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current passing is DC then the electrical resistance doesn't depend on shape. If the current passing is AC then, due to [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), the electrical resistance is influenced by shape. This is why multistrand conductors are preferred at high frequencies and high powers (see [Litz wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire)): -

[image]